# Xively REST API with cURL - 403 Forbidden

Tags: api, rest, curl, xively

I'm trying to follow the xively [cURL tutorial](https://xively.com/dev/tutorials/curl/). I have created new device in develop mode, copied the default auto-generated API key (with READ, WRITE, CREATE, DELETE permissions) to the example in tutorial and get response:

```
{"title":"Forbidden","errors":"You do not have the necessary permissions to access this resource"}
```

I must be missing some obvious step. Do I need to activate the API key somehow before using it in scripts?

The cURL command:

```
curl --request POST \
--data '{"title":"My feed", "version":"1.0.0"}' \
--header "X-ApiKey: cPHLfGw1WJdMAbU8FzbfsdFyJ8suayHEH3OChRrkpYwQCmrb" \ 
--verbose \
https://api.xively.com/v2/feeds
```

full verbose output:

```
* About to connect() to api.xively.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 216.52.233.120...
* Connected to api.xively.com (216.52.233.120) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA
* Server certificate:
*    subject: C=US; postalCode=01801; ST=MA; L=Woburn; street=First Floor; street=500 Unicorn Park Drive; O=LogMeIn Inc.; OU=Secure Link SSL Wildcard; CN=*.xively.com
*    start date: 2013-05-07 00:00:00 GMT
*    expire date: 2014-04-27 23:59:59 GMT
*    subjectAltName: api.xively.com matched
*    issuer: C=US; O=Network Solutions L.L.C.; CN=Network Solutions Certificate Authority
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST /v2/feeds HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: api.xively.com
> Accept: */*
> X-ApiKey: cPHLfGw1WJdMAbU8FzbfsdFyJ8suayHEH3OChRrkpYwQCmrb
> Content-Length: 38
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* upload completely sent off: 38 out of 38 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Date: Sat, 30 Nov 2013 11:03:15 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 98
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Request-Id: 6cbb9676b448a4967187271dd246b423f7da2e39
< 
* Connection #0 to host api.xively.com left intact
{"title":"Forbidden","errors":"You do not have the necessary permissions to access this resource"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you are trying to do. POST requests to api.xively.com/v2/feeds are no longer supported with any API key. This is because, since the implementation of devices, programatic creation of feeds directly is no longer supported.

This is an oversight in the Xively tutorial and I will inform the appropriate people to make sure that it gets changed.

In the mean time, since you have already created a device, you are basically ready to start the cURL tutorial at step 3 "Update a Feed". Use the API key and Feed ID from the development device you have already created on the website. Make sure to change your URL, body, and from a POST request to a PUT request.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I have no trouble updating existing feeds, so all OK now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add your feed id onto the end of the URL.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It is not written in the official tutorial that way, but sure makes sense. But it does not help: `curl --request POST --data '{"title":"test", "version":"1.0.0"}' --header "X-ApiKey: cPHLfGw1WJdMAbU8FzbfsdFyJ8suayHEH3OChRrkpYwQCmrb" --verbose https://api.xively.com/v2/feeds/1242861948` ends with the same error message as above: `{"title":"Forbidden","errors":"You do not have the necessary permissions to access this resource"}`

Comment: Sorry. I answered without understanding first. I don't use cURL.The example command your using is to create a feed, not to update an existing feed. Your key only gives access to the one feed you already created. The example needs a master key, which you won't want to post here. Hope this helps.